# Can Apache / mod_ssl support two-tier operation?

Tags: python, django, apache, centos, mod-ssl

I have a web server that maintains most of its content in a local database, but needs to query a back-end directory service to retrieve user information.  The directory query works fine as a stand-alone operation, but when the web server makes the query, ssl returns an error.

The server is based on `CentOS 7-2.1511 / Django 1.9.3 / PostgreSQL 9.2.15 / Apache 2.4.6-40 / mod_ssl 1:2.4.6-40 / OpenSSL 1:1.0.1 / Python 3.4.3`.  Apache uses mod_ssl to serve https: requests from the client (browser), and I'm assuming Python's ssl.py uses the same engine to make https: requests to the directory server.  [Python SSL](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ssl.html) says that it's implementation is based on OpenSSL.  [Yum](https://superuser.com/questions/294662/how-to-get-list-of-dependencies-of-non-installed-rpm-package) apparently can't list mod_ssl's dependencies, but I assume it also uses the installed version of openssl.

The following code will take the user's distinguished name (extracted from SSL_CLIENT_CERT) and query the directory server for the user's attributes using a RESTful interface:

```
import requests, urllib

URL = 'https://example.com/rest/user_info/'

def get_user_info(dn)
    query = URL + urllib.parse.quote(dn)
    return requests.get(query, cert=('server.crt', 'server.key'),
                        verify='ca_bundle.crt').json()
```

When I am running on the server as user apache in the server's WSGI directory the routine correctly returns a dict containing user attributes:

```
$ python
>>> import auth
>>> dn='cn=Me,o=Company,c=US'
>>> attr = auth.get_user_info(dn)
```

But when Apache calls the same function with the same DN from it's WSGI script (`views.py`), it raises an OSError:

```
OSError(0, 'Error')
Line 810, /lib64/python3.4/ssl.py

803  def do_handshake(self, block=False):
804      """Perform a TLS/SSL handshake."""
805      self._check_connected()
806      timeout = self.gettimeout()
807      try:
808          if timeout == 0.0 and block:
809              self.settimeout(None)
810          self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

I will start researching locking as suggested for [OpenSSL](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.openssl.users/L_5IxMnnX3w) (since I can't think of anything else that would be causing these errors) but it's hard to believe that a webserver using SSL for backend queries isn't already a well-traveled path.   Questions:

1. Is multi-threading / locking / reentrancy barking up the right tree for the cause of these errors?
2. Are there already worked examples for using SSL for webserver-backend connections?

Comment: The first thing that popped into my eye: you sre using relative pathes to the certificate files. Your working directory might differ in the Apache environment.

Comment: Good thought, but I simplified the example code from what I'm actually running.  My working directory is the same as the code running on the server (a Django app directory `/srv/django/myapp`) and I have absolute path variables for SERVER_CERT, SERVER_KEY, and CA_BUNDLE.  I have a single Python virtual environment on the server that is used by the Apache virtual host WSGIDaemon command and by my command line experiments, and as I said I'm running under user:group apache:apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up.  The following works reliably, at the expense of both beauty and efficiency.  It tries a `requests` query first, and if that blows up, it punts and calls `wget` in a subprocess.  It returns a meta item `$method` that lets the page view know whether the inline request failed.

```
def get_user_info(dn, sub=True, ttl=300):
    query = URL + urllib.parse.quote(dn)
    try:
        info = requests.get(query, cert=(SERVER_CERT, SERVER_KEY),
                            verify=CA_CERT).json()
        info['$method'] = 'requests'
        return info
    except OSError:
        if sub:
            args = ['wget', '-O', '-',
                '--certificate=' + SERVER_CERT,
                '--private-key=' + SERVER_KEY,
                query]
            bytes = subprocess.check_output(args, timeout=5)
            info = json.loads(bytes.decode(encoding='utf-8'))
            info['$method'] = 'subprocess'
            return info
        else:
            raise
```

It sure would be nice if OpenSSL used contexts instead of global variables.